# Why is the Facebook api returning #access_token vs ?access_token?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm making a call to facebook's api to get an oauth token.  The process seems to work but the call back url is returned like this

```
http://localhost:52574/FacebookApi/AuthorizeCallback#access_token=CODE&expires_in=6953
```

I would expect the #access_token parameter to be returned as a standard query string parameter not a hash.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Here is the code I'm using to generate the call back uri.

```
 public static Uri GetAuthorizationUri(string appId, string appSecret, string callBackUrl)
    {
        return new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
           "client_id=" + appId +
           "&redirect_uri=" + callBackUrl +
           "&scope=publish_actions,publish_stream,create_event" +
           "&response_type=token" );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing &response_type=code correctly returns a code that can then be exchanged for a token.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that in [that login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) it's expected to be a fragment to prevent leaking the access token to third party sites - it's also documented as such in the documentation for the `response_type` parameter:

`token`. Response data is included as a URL fragment and contains an access token. Desktop apps must use this setting for response_type. This is most useful when the client will be handling the token.